# Relational calculus to SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following relational calculus that I'm trying to turn into SQL.

```
{ a | ∃b X(a, b) ∧ ¬∃c ( Y(c) ∧ ¬X(a, c)) }
```

And I understand it must be something along the lines:

```
SELECT X1.a
FROM X X1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM X, Y 
    WHERE ... AND NOT ...
)
```

From my understanding it looks at table X and for each record in it, it checks all records in Y such that each and every record from Y must be in X with same value of attribute `a` as we were checking.

But I cannot exactly figure out how to turn it into SQL.

Edit:

To put this into a better perspective in plain English: 
Let `X` denote a `reservations` table, where `a` is `personID` and `b` is `item`. Let `Y` be a table of some subset of `items` table and `c` attribute be `item`.

From my understanding we are looking at cases where we are returning `personID`s based on this condition:

For every record in `reservations`, check whether this person also reserved ALL other `item`s from `Y`, if that is the case, return him.

I might be wrong, but this is my understanding based of this.

Comment: Can you put the relational calculus on english? Long time dont read those :P Speciall the `|` I remember the rest.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I guess something like this: "{ return a | exists b in X(a, b) and not exists c ( in Y(c) and not in X(a, c,)) }

Comment: Would it be heretical if I ask you to include sample data for your tables?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not exactly sure how would a sample data tables help. Basically my professor said that any relational calculus (in such a form as provided above) can be turned to SQL and this process is standardised... but I cannot seem to manage it :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out this problem is actually a "division" operation, that is, if we have set {2, 1, 4} and divide it by set {4, 1}, we get {1, 4} as the result.

Hence the SQL would be as following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT X1.a
FROM X X1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT *
                  FROM Y
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                                     SELECT *
                                     FROM X X2
                                     WHERE (X2.a=X1.a) AND (X2.b=Y.c)
                                   )
                 );
```

Hence when we run it on dataset:

R:

```
 x  | y
----+----
  1 | 1
  2 | 1
  2 | 2
  2 | 3
  1 | 2
  3 | 1
  4 | 3
```

and

S:

```
 c
----
 1
 2
```

We should expect to get {1, 2} back as these are the only `persons` who "borrowed all items from S".

Comment: I know this post is kinda old, but have you found any technique to optimizing such queries (automatically)? I am converting tuple calculus terms to sql queries and they quickly become very slow.

Answer (score 0):

> ∃b X(a, b)

Can be this

```
SELECT X.a
FROM X
WHERE X.b IS NOT NULL    -- mean ( a, b ) are in X
```

OR extend to something like

```
SELECT X.a 
FROM X
JOIN Q 
  ON X.b  = Q.b
```

> ¬∃c ( Y(c) ∧ ¬X(a, c)) }

Same idea

```
SELECT X.a
FROM X
WHERE c IS NULL  -- mean ¬X(a, c)
```

So

```
NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
             FROM Y
             JOIN X
               ON X.c = Y.c)
```

Comment: Have to polish last step, but have to go now. So hope that help you start